# Search people not find any user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, people-search

I have not configured Enterprise serarch but normal search. When I go to My Site at the top of the page there is a textbox which contain "Search fo persons". When I enter a username and press enter no result found.

Do I need to have profile Synchronization?

When I go to "User Profile Service Application" at the right side of the page it says "Number of profiles 21" and when I go to Content Source of Search Service Application I can find sps3://dev
So does it means that the users has been crawled? What must I need to do to make search find the users? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are pretty much all the way there. A couple things I would make sure:

- Are you missing any key alternate access mapping entries? Sometimes mismatched alternate access mappings can cause problems with search though I don't know if this would be your exact problem
- Have you run a full crawl since the user profile import? This is what I'm leaning towards most. I believe that new users found during the user profile sync will not show up unless you do a full crawl. Incremental would not be sufficient. For this reason you may want to split your users into a separate content source so that you can continue to do incremental crawls on your data, and full crawls on people.

Comment: thanks, I am on my development environment and trying to make search people work. when I go to AAM I can see all web applications.

my question is do I need make a user sychronization? how do you make a profile import? 

Yes I have run full crawl.

Comment: "When I go to "User Profile Service Application" at the right side of the page it says "Number of profiles 21" is what you said in your post which means you have run a user profile import at least once. Are you expecting more than 21 profiles?

Comment: No I am not expectiong more than 21 users. I meant do I need to run it again. why when I search for my user "test1" it finds only documents and lists which test1 is been active (as owner of a document or komment which contains test1)??

Comment: Ok, you shouldn't have to do another profile sync then. Are you on http or https? If https your search crawl entry should be sps3s instead of sps3.

Comment: Also, are there any errors in your crawl log regarding the sps3 content source?

Comment: I am on http and the crawl protocol is sps3:// and for each web applications I have added one sps3://.  no errors regarding sps3 only errors regarding web applications which has been removed but still it tries to crawl them.